# Pandas column of lists: How to get the average, max length, and standard deviation of the list lengths of that column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column containing lists of ints, which vary in length.

I am wondering how to get the max, average, and standard deviation of the length of those lists.

So far, I found this command

`df['lists'].str.len()`

Which seems to give the length for each row. Although I am not 100% sure if this is the proper command for my case. But if it is, I would then need to get the average, max, and stddev of those values.

Comment: Please include a sample of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `df['lists'].str.len()` gives you lengths of lists in your series. To get the stats:

```
df['lists'].str.len().agg(['mean','max','std'])
```